# How to expose properties to Lua Library from C++

Tags: c++, lua

I want to how we can expose properties to lua library.

```
luaL_openlib( L, kName, kVTable, 1 ); // leave "library" on top of stack
```

With this, I am able to expose only functions as kVTable refers to luaL_Reg

```
typedef struct luaL_Reg {
  const char *name;
  lua_CFunction func;
} luaL_Reg;
```

Eg: With the above code. I can do following.

```
local myLib = require "plugin.myLib"
myLib.newFunc();
```

However, I want to expose Lua Table to the library as CONSTANTS variable.

```
myLib.CONSTANTS.SOME_CONST_1
myLib.CONSTANTS.SOME_CONST_2
```

etc. Please let me know how can I expose lua Table from my library as property.

Comment: Which version of Lua do you use? AFAIK luaL_openlib was removed in Lua 5.1.

Comment: @peterm I am using CORONA Enterprise. From the header files I could see that they are using Lua 5.1. From Lua 5.1 manual, it says that Function luaL_openlib was replaced by luaL_register. luaL_register also takes array of luaL_Reg, which means I can only pass table with key(string) and values as cfunctions. I want even set table to the values.

Comment: @kapser If your're exposing a very limited set of API from `C`, you can use what @peterm suggested. But for something more extensive (esp. if it is `C++`, as against `C`), you can consider using a lua API wrapper like [luabind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind/docs.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `luaL_openlib` leaves the library table on top on the stack, you can use regular C API to add new fields and subtables to it:

```
luaL_openlib( L, kName, kVTable, 1 ); // leaves "library" on top of stack
lua_pushstring(L, "CONSTANTS"); 
lua_newtable(L); // this will be CONSTANTS subtable

lua_pushstring(L, "SOME_CONST_1");
lua_pushnumber(L, 42); // SOME_CONST_1 value
lua_settable(L, -3); // sets SOME_CONST_1

lua_pushstring(L, "SOME_CONST_2");
lua_pushnumber(L, 12345); // SOME_CONST_2 value
lua_settable(L, -3); // sets SOME_CONST_2

lua_settable(L, -3); // sets CONSTANTS table as field of the library table
return 1;
```

Comment: Thanks peter. It has helped me understand more about lua and how to push elements in the lua stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you use C++, you can use a binding library, such as the header-only [luabridge](http://vinniefalco.com/LuaBridge/Manual.html#s2.2) to bind some data to named tables in Lua. Transforming your example into LuaBridge, call this function after you initialize your Lua state:

```
void register_constants (lua_State* L) {

    luabridge::getGlobalNamespace(L)
        .beginNamespace("myLib")
            .beginNamespace("CONSTANTS")
                .addVariable("SOME_CONST_1",&some_const_1,false/*read-only*/)
                .addVariable("SOME_CONST_2",&some_const_2,false/*read-only*/)
            .endNamespace()
        .endNamespace()
    ;
}
```

...

```
lua_State* L=lua_open();
register_constants(L);
...
```

you can access the constants as your last code snippet

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat, lector*, because Lua C API is, well, C API.

The whole burden with `loadlib` and friends was because functions are much harder to pass using C (C funcions aren't first class values). So my best bet would be to set all those constants using regular stack API.

In general, it is supposed to be used to exchange runtime data, of course, but there's no inherent reason why you shouldn't be able to fill your tables with that when loading the module.